# How to separate values using Sub string for sql Eg-Data 42ND-1000 W61ST-1000 TIFF-1000 THIR-1000 and i want data before - eg-42ND

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting the following data:

```
42ND-1000 
W61ST-1000 
TIFF-1000 
THIR-1000
```

and I want to get the data before the `-`.

For `42ND-1000` I want `42ND` only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basic string manipulation.  In SQL Server, you would do:

```
select left(col, charindex('-', col + '-')- 1)
```